# How to get rid of Dreamweaver Tooltips?

Tags: user-interface, dreamweaver, tooltip

I have this annoying tooltip that I can't turn off. It seems to get stuck in design view on certain html documents. How can I turn it off completely? Happens on hover over page in design view, and it never goes away! I'm on MacOS dreamweaver version 21.3

Even a slight move of the mousepad triggers that popup, even outside of tables :/

[image: Annoying Adobe Tooltip]

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/how-to-disable-tooltips-in-tables-in-dreamweaver-cc2017/td-p/8922888 says you can't

Comment: @Destroy666 the tooltip does disappear on some pages I'm working on quite quickly, on others, it just stays on screen and it is so annoying :/ is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've ever seen, there's no way to turn off the various table tip pop-ups in Design View.

However, DWCC2017 allows for editing tables in Live View where that pop up doesn't exist. It might be worthwhile for you to investigate the Live View Editor when working with table-based layouts.

To start, click the table in Live so the blue Table tab appears, then hit the small menu icon in the tab to access the editing functions.

[Source](https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/how-to-disable-tooltips-in-tables-in-dreamweaver-cc2017/td-p/8922888)